# Angular with markdown files : style of component affecting other component's style

Tags: css, angular, components, markdown

HTML Template of `ComponentA`

```
<app-tooltip [chemin]="'../../assets/markdowns/typeDisk.md'"></app-tooltip>
<table>
.
.
.
</table>
```

TooltipComponent :

```
import { Component, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  template: `<i (click)="openMarkDown()" class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>`,
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css']
})
export class TooltipComponent {

  @Input() chemin: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openMarkDown(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MarkDownOverview, {
      data: this.chemin,
      panelClass: 'my-parent-class'
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  template: `
    <i class="fas fa-times fa-lg" (click)="onNoClick()"></i>
    <div class="my-parent-class" markdown [src]="data"></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css']
})
export class MarkDownOverview {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MarkDownOverview>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

So basically what it does is when the `<i>` is clicked, it opens a Material dialog containing a markdown file content. In this markdow file content, I do a table like this :

```
| COLUMN | COLUMN | COLUMN |
| :----: | :----: | :----: |
|  ....  |  ....  |  ....  |
|  ....  |  ....  |  ....  |
|  ....  |  ....  |  ....  |
|  ....  |  ....  |  ....  |
```

Markdown tables have by default no style, so I added some style for the table in the markdown file :

```
table {
  padding: 0;
}

table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 13px;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 13px;
}

table tr th :first-child, table tr td :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

table tr th :last-child, table tr td :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The thing is that the CSS also affect the table of Component A, and that's problematic, because they don't have the same style.

Comment: The styleUrls property in both @Component decorators is the same.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the <style></style> in the markdown file affect `ComponentA`and to be honest I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of style encapsulation. The style in your component only applies to elements created by your component by default.

Try modifying the coomponent hosting the markdown to use `::ng-deep`

```
:host .my-parent-class ::ng-deep
{

    table {
      padding: 0;
    }

    table tr {
      border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
}
```